# How to create HotSpot in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a hotspot on image in my winform application. I followed the solution posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270147/creating-hotspots-in-c-sharp), but I don't know where I should put the coordinates to make this method work:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent) 
{ 
     string X = mouseEvent.X.ToString();
     string Y = mouseEvent.Y.ToString(); 
}
```

Where should I put the coordinates? I have two coordinates (X,Y): 110, 45

Comment: I don't know where I should put the coordinates and image. Could you please help me in completing the code.

Comment: what is the name of the container that contains your image.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to respond to the mouse being over a [rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991.aspx) within the image:

```
private Rectangle _hotspot = new Rectangle(20, 30, 10, 10);

protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (_hotspot.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            // respond to the mouse being in the hotspot
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What about if I have an image called (img1) and I want to create a hotspot on it with any coordinates. Where should I define it? and how I will assign the coordinates to it?

Comment: Do you want the user to create the hotspot?

Comment: No, the hotspot will be created by my. I want to add the image to my form and when the user mouseover it on specific coordiantes, this area will be clickable.

Comment: That is what my code does. All you have to do is enter the correct position and size of the hotspot.

Comment: I change the code to respond to the click of the left moouse button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place an image on those coordinates you need to set the top and left of that image with those coordinates

```
double X = mouseEvent.X;
double Y = mouseEvent.Y;

pictureBox.Top = X;
pictureBox.Left = Y;
```

if you only wanted to know forexample when somebody hoovers over the picturebox then use this event

```
private void pictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
{

 // do here what you want
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to add the coordinates to the method and making it works well. Could you please help me in modifying it?

Comment: Where should I put the coordinates?

Comment: you are using a picturebox right ? i so there must a 2 properties called top and left, use those to set the properties

Comment: Actually, I am a new C# developer and trying to learn. I just know the PictureBox from you. So if it is possible, provide me with an example about it.

Comment: I am trying to complete the method that I wrote in my question but I don't know how.

Comment: If you could be more specific i could probably help you better

Comment: OK. I have a form and I inserted an image in it. I want to specify a specific part of this image to be clickable. I use pictureBox to insert the image. I have the following coordinates (116, 46) that I want it to be clickable in the image.