# Add Invisible Control and use Control.MouseHover Event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have developed a board game. I want to add one more feature onto it. If I move my cursor onto one of the entry on the game board. It will show relevant information right next to the cursor. I know I can add invisible controls onto the game board and use Control.MouseHover Event to make this feature work. However, what kind of invisible control I can add onto the board? The rectangle shape will be most useful. One more question, how to display text right next to the cursor? I have attached the board I was talking about in below.
[image]
 Thank you for helping me.

Comment: `I have developed a board game`  I'm pretty sure that game was already invented/developed in the 1930s.  Invisible controls wont fire events

Comment: It is not clear here what are you asking. Also, it is better not to ask different questions in one post, Please, split it, because I don't see how these questions are related.

Comment: I am not sure if you know what sprites are but search *image sprites in winforms* and that will help you. Also you can draw rectangles on the board as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11325260/4228458) and create mouseover events for it. Sprites are better though.

Comment: @Alex Butenko Thanks for your reply, I'll split the question into two posts. Do you know how to display a text message just right near the cursor in Windows Form.

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks, I made a grammar mistake, what I mean is that I made a game based on the rules and format of existing Monopoly game.

Comment: You could just use the toolTip property to display a text message right next to the cursor - that is what it was designed for.  To do this, drop a ToolTip control on your form (let's say it's called toolTip1).  Then just assign your text to the `ToolTip on toolTip1` property of the control that you want to show a tool tip next to.