# How to create HotSpot in C# with PictureBox?

Tags: c#

I am a new C# developer and I want to create a hotspot in an image that I put in my winform application. I followed the solution posted [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270147/creating-hotspots-in-c-sharp), but I did not know where I should put the coordinates to make this method works:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs mouseEvent) 
{ 
     string X = mouseEvent.X.ToString();
     string Y = mouseEvent.Y.ToString(); 
}
```

Where should I put the coordinates? I have two coordinates (X,Y): 110, 45

Comment: "Hotspot" is only relevant to a cursor, not an image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating HotSpots in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270147/creating-hotspots-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Hotspot I feel should be a small rectangular area rather than just a coordinate. Suppose you want it to be a small square area of width 20 then you would write something like this:

EDIT:

Suppose you have a PictureBox on your form called PictureBox1 and you want that a small rectangle of say 20x20 size starting from Top-Left corner of the picturebox become a hotspot (i.e. when you take mouse over it you would see a HAND cursor) then on the MouSeMove event of the PictureBox write this:

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X > 0 && e.X < 20 && e.Y > 0 && e.Y < 20)
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
        else
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Please remember, we are just showing the Hand Cursor to denote a hotspot we have not yet handled a Click for that matter, to make it really a web kind hotspot. If you want to do something on Click, try using the MouseUp event, in the MouseUp event the same IF clause as above would give you the condition that user has clicked on the hotspot region.

Comment: Could you please add the image to your code and show me how it will work with this code?

Comment: On a WinForm add a PictureBox ensure that the picturebox is at least say 150x100 pixel in size, add an image to the picturebox and handle the MouseMove event of the picturebox. In the MouseMove event write what I have written inside the OnMouseMove code above...I have edited my answr above please refer that....